# How to make a pie chart from highcharts responsive

Tags: css, charts, highcharts

I am trying since some days to make a pie chart from highcharts responsive. I am working on a medium size project and sometimes it is easy to lose the overview.

I already checked this : http://www.angulartutorial.net/2014/03/responsive-highchart.html but no success.

**Problem:** The highchart looks good when the width is 1920px.
         When it is 900px then the description of the pie (series -> data) is outside the browser and one can not read it, moreover, the pie is for me to small.

**Question:** How can I avoid this behaviour? I would like a bigger pie and be able to read the (series-> data).

I provide the following code:

My HTML code is:

```
<div id="container-independency" >
  <div id="independency" >
    <div>Title plot</div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2.8%; margin-top:1%; font-size: 24px;">Bla blablabla blab bl<span class="autarkie" > </span> % blabla = <strong> <span class="autarkie" >
    </span> % blablabla blablabla</strong></div>
     <div id="highcharts_container"></div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS code:

```
#container-independency{
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1620px;
    background-color: #b8860b;
    clear: both;
    padding: 1%;
    display: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#independency{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 1%;
    background-color: #ffb6c1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#highcharts_container{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}
```

Highcharts:

```
('#highcharts_container').highcharts({ 
          chart: { 
              plotBackgroundColor: null, 
              plotBorderWidth: null, 
              plotShadow: false, 
              type: 'pie' 
          },

          title:{
           text:''
          },

          credits: { 
            enabled: false 
           },

          navigation: {
            buttonOptions: {
                enabled: false
            }
          }, 

          tooltip: { 
              pointFormat: '<b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>' 
          }, 
          plotOptions: { 
              pie: { 
                  allowPointSelect: true, 
                  cursor: 'pointer', 
                  dataLabels: { 
                      enabled: true, 
                      format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.2f} %', 
                      style: { 
                          color: '#58585a',
                          fontFamily: 'klavika-web, sans-serif', fontSize: '12px'          
                      } 
                  } 
              } 
          }, 
          series: [{

              name: '',    
              data: [ 
                 ['Property1aaa/Property2aaa/Property3aaaaaa', independency], 
                 ['More blablabla blablabla', 100-independency],                
              ] 
          }]    
        });//highcharts_container
```

Update:

[image: Labels are hidden]

Comment: Why display: none; for #container-independency? Chart is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Each time a chart changes size redraw event of a chart is triggered. You can check width of a chart in that event and call additional update for series, because if you change your labels' text to one with `<br>` tags, then pie seems to be fitting well. In case your issue is more complex solution will still be similar - check size and update chart.

Example with changed point names: http://jsfiddle.net/j86jkfvj/114/

Example with series update when width is < 900px: http://jsfiddle.net/dhwzw8qg/

Comment: Thks for the answer. This is exactly my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/dhwzw8qg/ . When resizing the browser, then the pie is hidden.

Comment: @webquestions When pie is hidden? How to recreate the problem and what is your expected, final behavior of chart?

Comment: I added the case when the screen is smaller. When the screen is smaller look that the labels are hidden. Thats my problem. How can I avoid this?

Comment: @webquestions You could add another if case in your fitting function. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dhwzw8qg/1/ In case chart is vary small you could try with disabled dataLabels and optionally legend instead or not.

Comment: Maybe it is a good idea to disable the labels after some width: ex. 600px. Thx @Kacper Madej

Comment: I found this, so can't take credit, but appears to be a much better answer, with a resize event triggering a redraw of the chart:

http://jsfiddle.net/4mo2qf79/12/

Comment: @NicoWesterdale Yes, this looks better. You should put it as an answer. Link your source if you don't want to take the credit for the code :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example I found of redrawing the pie based on a resize event of the page. I've used it and works well:

[jsfiddle.net/4mo2qf79/12](http://jsfiddle.net/4mo2qf79/12)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="container" style="width:100%;"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
       },
        title: {
            text: 'Responsive Resize'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox', 45.0],
                ['IE',      26.8],
                ['Safari',  8.5],
                ['Opera',   6.2],
                ['Others',  0.7]
            ]
        }]
    });

    function redrawchart(){
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

        console.log('redraw');
        var w = $('#container').closest(".wrapper").width()
        // setsize will trigger the graph redraw 
        chart.setSize(       
            w,w * (3/4),false
        );
     }

    $(window).resize(redrawchart);
    redrawchart();

});
```