# How to set the width of HighCharts fit within the Grid

Tags: css, reactjs, highcharts

I have below code in ReactJs which uses material ui `Grid` to align the high-charts, but the chart width did not fit with the width of the screen which it should be as it is in the `Grid`, rather there is ample of `whitespace` between first and second chart.

```
<Grid container item xs={12} md={12} style={{ marginLeft: '0.5%' }}>
<Grid container item xs={6} md={6}>
    <LineChart
        chartData={ChartData1}
    />
</Grid>

<Grid container item xs={6} md={6}>
    <LineChart
        chartData={ChartData2}
    />
</Grid>
```

I am not giving any `width` in my highChart configuration. What's wrong in my design?

Comment: May be this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118711/how-to-make-a-pie-chart-from-highcharts-responsive

Comment: Hi @Lara, First of all, I recommend you to use the officially supported `Highcharts React` wrapper: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official Next, please add the name of the `grid` package you are using.